# Regex to match exact phrase, nothing before or after the phrase

Tags: regex

I am not sure if this is exactly possible. Consider this example set of data:

```
Mountain
Big mountain
Mountain of stone
A mountain on a hill
```

I want to match Mountain. Nothing else. No other parts of that set. Just the exact line, Mountain. Everything I've tried either matches for all instances of Mountain or for none of them. Plenty of people want to match an exact word or phrase, but I seem to be the only one who wants to match only one exact word or phrase.

If this CAN be expanded to a phrase that would be perfect. Assume:

```
Go for a hike
Go for a hike, on a mountain.
I want to go for a hike.
```

Where I want to match only "Go for a hike" but no phrase that contains it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To match the exact line "Mountain" use this:  `/^Mountain$/`

You haven't mentioned what language you're working in, so the exact form of the pattern might have to change.

Comment: @jahroy: Actually, `^` means beginning *of input*, and `$` means end *of input* (or just before a newline at end of input).  It's only when you specify multiline mode (`/^Mountain$/m`, or `"(?m)^Mountain$"`) that they mean beginning and end *of line*.

Comment: Good point.  I was just trying to explain the symbols to the OP.  In this case, the input will be a line of text (presumeably).

Comment: I'm completely unsure of what language is being used, it's a database on a website that supports searches by regex patterns, but this worked exactly for what I needed it for. Thank you very much. I was trying to do this by specifying mountain as a word boundary (the \b thing) and could not for the life of me see how else to do this.

Comment: @phobiac, he means what programming lang do you want to use this regex in. Like PHP or JS.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string that contains multiple lines, the following two regular expressions may help:

```
\r\nWORD\r\n|^WORD\r\n|\r\WORD$|^WORD$

\r\nA\sPHRASE\r\n|^A\sPHRASE\r\n|\r\A\sPHRASE$|^A\sPHRASE$
```

Comment: The person above had an expression that worked perfectly for what I needed, but thank you for the suggestion. I'll try this for phrases if I have trouble.