# Applying grep on a list with a pattern before and after

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a list of words, that I want to replace in a tbl_df.

This is the data.

```
    data<-tbl_df(c("05+12+TIP", "eintippen", "MyTipStar", "05TIP", "TIP","05+12+HERO", "einhero", "MyHEROStar", "05HERO", "HERO"))
```

This is the pattern I want to find.

```
    pat<-c("TIP", "HERO", "good")
```

This would work with this Code leading to this result:

```
    data$value <-gsub(paste(pat, collapse="|", ignore.case== TRUE), "", data$value )
     [1] "05+12+"    "eintippen" "MyTipStar" "05"        ""          "05+12+"    "einhero"   "MyStar"    "05"        ""
```

I want to look for all the entries of pat but in front and behind cannot be letters.

```
     [1] "05+12+"    "eintippen" "MyTipStar" "05"        ""          "05+12+"    "ein"   "MyHEROStar"    "05"        ""
```

So I would not find "eintippen", because this tip has left an n and right a p.

Comment: Can you show the expected

Comment: I added it in the original post.

Comment: try `grep(paste(paste0("^",pat,"$"), collapse="|"), data$value, value = T)`. Coud be a [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552877/regex-to-match-exact-phrase-nothing-before-or-after-the-phrase)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do it in 2 steps:

```
data <- c("05+12+TIP", "eintippen", "MyTipStar", "05TIP", "TIP","05+12+HERO", "einhero", "MyHEROStar", "05HERO", "HERO")
pat <- c("TIP", "HERO", "good")
mask <- grepl(paste0("([^[:alpha:]]|^)(",paste(pat, collapse="|"), ")([^[:alpha:]]|$)"), data, ignore.case= TRUE)
data[mask] = gsub(paste(pat, collapse="|"), ignore.case= TRUE, "", data[mask])
data
```

See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html for explanation of [:alpha:]

Answer (score 0):

> look for all the entries of pat but in front and behind cannot be letters

You need to use a PCRE regex with lookarounds (otherwise, when you use capturing group approach, you won't be able to handle consecutive matches if any):

```
value <- c("05+12+TIP", "eintippen", "MyTipStar", "05TIP", "TIP","05+12+HERO", "einhero", "MyHEROStar", "05HERO", "HERO")
data <- data.frame(value)
pat<-c("TIP", "HERO", "good")
regex = paste0("(?<![[:alpha:]])(?:", paste(pat, collapse="|"), ")(?![[:alpha:]])")
regex
gsub(regex, "", data$value, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE )
## [1] "05+12+"     "eintippen"  "MyTipStar"  "05"         ""          
## [6] "05+12+"     "einhero"    "MyHEROStar" "05"         ""
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/hkdFOC)

The regex is

```
(?<![[:alpha:]])(?:TIP|HERO|good)(?![[:alpha:]])
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8iMlDE/1/). Its details:

- `(?<![[:alpha:]])` - (a negative lookbehind) no letter is allowed to the left of the current location
- `(?:TIP|HERO|good)` - match either of the 3 alternatives
- `(?![[:alpha:]])` - (a negative lookahead) no letter is allowed to the right of the current location.